# "Endorse" vs. "condone"

Tags: differences, verbs, nouns, connotation, analogy

What is the difference in meaning/connotation between the two words? Is *endorse* "stronger", more positive?

Also, *endorse* is to *endorsement* as *condone* is to what? Is there a noun counterpart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "endorse" is to say that you approve of something, you are for it. To "condone" is to say that you accept or tolerate it. You condone something that you think is a bad idea or a wrong action but that is forgivable or understandable given the circumstances. You endore seomthing that you think is a positive good and that you encourage. So yes, "endorse" is a much stronger positive.

thefreedictionary.com lists "condonation" as the noun form of "condone", but I don't recall ever seeing this word used. If you need it, it's there, but I'd avoid it as unlikely to be familiar to your audience.

Comment: Thanks, special thanks about the warning about "condonation".

Answer (score 2):

*Endorse* has a more positive connotation than does *condone*.

*Condone* means you have overlooked an offense (possibly without comment). It is often used in a negative sense: "I cannot condone your behavior."

*Endorse* means you give something or someone a thumbs-up, an approval, and your support, usually publicly. There are numerous examples of its use in this American election year.

The noun form of *condone* is *condonation*, [defined as](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/condonation): the act of condoning, especially the implied forgiveness of an offense by ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

They mean completely different things. Merriam-Webster has

- **endorse** to approve openly; to recommend
- **condone** to treat something blameworthy as acceptable (or at least, not unacceptable)

ODO has *condonation* for the noun.